# Flutter Drawer is not visible and the page gives error

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm routing menu with Drawer. It works fine for 2 pages but there is one page gives error.

The menu works correctly when I first press it, then when I go to another page and come back it gives this error

Also I tryed routing with routes on mainApp buut this way seemed easier to me

[image]

My drawer

```
class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Align(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[                  
                  Text(
                    "Test",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Main'),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Main(),
                  ));
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.perm_device_information),
            title: Text('How'),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
            onTap: () {
              //Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/how");
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => HowItWorks(),
                  ));
            },
          ),  
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.keyboard),
            title: Text('Contact'),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
            onTap: () {
              //Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/contact");
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SendMail(),
                  ));
            },
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the page it gives error on second route and drawer is not visible

```
final _formKey2 = GlobalKey<FormState>();
class SendMail extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey2,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(48.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'İletişim',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                Text('Contact Me'),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Can not be empty';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              hintText: 'Name',
                              border: InputBorder.none),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              hintText: 'Email',
                              border: InputBorder.none),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          maxLines: 7,
                          validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Can not be empty';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              hintText: 'Message',
                              border: InputBorder.none),
                        ),
                      ),                      
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Detailed error

[image]

Comment: not able to see the image.

Comment: Check your run log for a more detailed error message

Comment: This page gives this error on second route

Comment: Try adding globalKey inside the class rather than outside. Also your Drawer widget does not need to be stateful.

Comment: Well it worked thank you but in this page drawer does not appear